# Why did Mona's name change in the later part of 3 idiots?

Tags: analysis, plot-explanation, 3-idiots

Mona Singh, whose name is Poonam, becomes Mona in the later part of the film [3 Idiots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_Idiots). After squabbling with Viru Sahasrbuddhe, Rancho suddenly starts calling 'Mona Push'.  After that everybody, including her father, starts calling her the same name.

Is this a movie mistake or was Mona her nickname in the film?

Comment: Its also mentioned here http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1187043/trivia?tab=gf

Comment: I got that, that's why i removed that comment before you reply, I even added a IMDB link for similar kind of mistakes

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Are they showing Mona as her nick name? Or they are forget their character name in movie:P

Comment: IMDB and wiki both shows her name as Mona only but IMDB goofs says its a mistake

Comment: Hm.seems like it is a plot hole. Good catch anyways @SomnathMuluk! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its discussed in many aritical and newspaper but There is no official clarification given for this and its seems only movie mistake or may be done purposely to use Mona's name as a parody to her original name.